# Rethinkdb python handle empty result

Tags: python, database, exception, rethinkdb

What is the best technique with rethinkb and python to deal with empty result.
I try this, but catching exceptions is not satisfactory.

```
@staticmethod
def get_by_mail(mail):
    try:
        return User(
            r.table('users').filter({"mail": mail}).limit(1).nth(0).run()
        )
    except RqlRuntimeError:
        return None
```

If anyone has tried other techniques, I am very interested.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to do in case of rql runtime error.

Comment: I want to return **None** or an empty dict {}

Comment: Then what way your approach is not satisfactory?

Comment: I want to reduce the boilerplate

Comment: He search something like that https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/362#issuecomment-13749061

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with this is probably by adding in the element you want back with a `union`.

```
r.table('users').filter({"mail": mail}).limit(1).union([{}])[0]
```

A slightly ugly work around but it should do the trick. I think we should probably extend the `default` syntax to work with this. I'm going to make an issue for that.

Comment: Thank you, I like this one liner.

Answer (score 1):

That should work

```
r.table('users').filter({"mail": mail}).do( lambda users:
    r.branch(
        users.count() == 1,
        users.nth(0),
        None
     )
 )
```

You can also remove the nth(0) and retrieve a cursor and do:

```
user = None
for i in user:
     user = i
     break # You don't really need to break since there is at most one element
```

Comment: Thank you, I give it a try too